# Starlink, Multi-WAN router, and blocked DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a TP-Link ER605 multi-WAN router at home, also a Raspberry Pi running dnsmasq for DNS. One WAN port of the router is connected to an AT&T DSL router and the other was connected to a T-Mobile Home 5G cellular access device. This setup has been stable for months with (to my dismay) the DSL link carrying most of the traffic.

My Starlink terminal came last week and is now installed. I hope I'm going to replace both AT&T and T-Mobile with it, but I can't make the network operate with Starlink in "bypass mode," which is the the supposedly preferred way to connect Starlink to a router. The connection from Starlink goes to the WAN port on the ER605 formerly used by the T-Mobile device.

The local network is 192.168.137.0/24; the default gateway is a LAN port on the ER605 with address 192.168.137.254. DNS is 192.168.137.250. The AT&T side of the router is 192.168.237.0/24, with AT&T's DSL modem being 192.168.237.254 and the ER605 WAN port 192.168.237.12. These are static addresses.

When Starlink is in bypass mode it has a network of 192.168.100.0/24 with the Starlink device being 192.168.100.1. I configured the ER605 to be 192.168.100.12. Statistics on the ER605 show that the Starlink is carrying traffic, but *my DNS no longer works!* It acts like my DNS server can't reach any upstream recursive resolvers.

However, if I tell the ER605 it has a dynamic connection and plug it into the Starlink, not in bypass mode, it gets an address of 192.168.1.23. My DNS works, and the Starlink is carrying the bulk of the traffic. Good. This is exactly what I wanted to happen.

What I don't understand, and my question for today, is **why does Starlink in bypass mode kill my DNS?** While I'm OK with the current situation, I'd really like to understand what's going on.

A possible hint: IPv6 is enabled everyplace there's a place, but https://test-ipv6.com reports no IPv6 on the StarLink connection. I'll have to move wires to reliably test the AT&T DSL, but it had IPv6 before StarLink.

**Update:** Taking the IP address of the Raspberry Pi DNS server out of the router's configuration for DNS server fixed the problem.  I don't have a clue why.  I came across this solution in another forum.  The poster there doesn't have a clue, either.

I'd still like to know what was going on.